# Getting END OF FILE Expected on Postman

Tags: json, request, postman, http-post, postman-pre-request-script

I'm using the following JSON body on a postman request and I'm getting a END OF FILE Expected error:

```json
"customer": {
"gender": 1,
"company": "MyCompany",
"name": "Doe",
"firstname": "John",
"phone": "0606060606"
,
"address": {
"address": "123 main street",
"address2": "456 second street",
"postalCode": 17101,
"city": "Anytown",
"country": "UK"
},
"references": [
123458,
154568
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`json` objects should start with `{` and end with `}`. You should have:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "gender": 1,
        "company": "MyCompany",
        "name": "Doe",
        "firstname": "John",
        "phone": "0606060606",
        "address": { 
            "address": "123 main street",
            "address2": "456 second street",
            "postalCode": 17101,
            "city": "Anytown",
            "country": "UK" 
            },
            "references": [ 123458, 154568 ] 
     }
 }
```